# SQL Results values in horizontal way

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables JOB and EMP; structure and values are like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE JOB 
(
    JOBID SMALLINT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    JOBNAME CHAR(15)
);

CREATE TABLE EMP
(
    EMPID SMALLINT, 
    JOBID SMALLINT, 
    SAL SMALLINT, 
    CITYID SMALLINT,
    YEAR SMALLINT,
    SEX  CHAR(1),
    STATE CHAR(2)
);

INSERT INTO JOB(JOBID, JOBNAME) 
VALUES (1, 'DEVELOPMENT'),
       (2, 'DEVELOPMENT'),
       (3, 'TESTING'),
       (4, 'TESTING'),
       (7, 'TESTING'),
       (8, 'HR'),
       (10,  'RESEARCH');

INSERT INTO EMP (EMPID , JOBID, SAL, CITYID, YEAR, SEX,STATE) 
VALUES (100, 1, 1000, 10, 2015, 'M','NY'),
       (200, 2, 2000, 10, 2015, 'M','NJ'),
       (300, 1, 2500, 20, 2015, 'F','NY'),
       (400, 3, 1000, 10, 2015, 'M','CA'),
       (500, 6, 3000, 10, 2015, 'F','NJ'),
       (600, 8, 1000, 30, 2015, 'M','CA'),
       (700, 8, 2000, 10, 2015, 'F','NY'),
       (800, 9, 1500, 10, 2015, 'F','CA');
```

For the given input cityid , YEAR ( Emp table), take all jobids for each jobname (from job table ) and match in Emp table, if exists display count (count of jobids present in Emp table) of each sex (male and female) for the states NY,NJ,CA in horizontal way; and totals as well. if there is no match display 0.

Output should be like this:

```
Jobname                  Male           FEMALE              TOTAL
                    NY   NJ   CA      NY   NJ   CA 

Development         1     1   0       1    0    0             3
TESTING             0     0   1       0    0    0             1
HR                  0     0   1       1    0    0             2
RESEARCH            0     0   0       0    0    0             0
TOTAL               1     1   2       2    0    0             6
```

How to get the results in horizontal way ..?

Comment: If it is a fixed number of states you can use case expressions to do conditional aggregation. It it is a unknown/dynamic number of states, check out SQL Server's PIVOT.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think this can be use :

```
 CREATE TABLE #JOB 
(
    JOBID SMALLINT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    JOBNAME CHAR(15)
);

CREATE TABLE #EMP
(
    EMPID SMALLINT, 
    JOBID SMALLINT, 
    SAL SMALLINT, 
    CITYID SMALLINT,
    YEAR SMALLINT,
    SEX  CHAR(1),
    STATE CHAR(2)
);

INSERT INTO #JOB(JOBID, JOBNAME) 
VALUES (1, 'DEVELOPMENT'),
       (2, 'DEVELOPMENT'),
       (3, 'TESTING'),
       (4, 'TESTING'),
       (7, 'TESTING'),
       (8, 'HR'),
       (10, 'RESEARCH');

INSERT INTO #EMP (EMPID , JOBID, SAL, CITYID, YEAR, SEX,STATE) 
VALUES (100, 1, 1000, 10, 2015, 'M','NY'),
       (200, 2, 2000, 10, 2015, 'M','NJ'),
       (300, 1, 2500, 20, 2015, 'F','NY'),
       (400, 3, 1000, 10, 2015, 'M','CA'),
       (500, 6, 3000, 10, 2015, 'F','NJ'),
       (600, 8, 1000, 30, 2015, 'M','CA'),
       (700, 8, 2000, 10, 2015, 'F','NY'),
       (800, 9, 1500, 10, 2015, 'F','CA');



    SELECT * FROM #JOB;

    SELECT * FROM #EMP;


    SELECT J.JOBNAME, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN E.SEX = 'M' AND STATE = 'NY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Male_NY',
        SUM(CASE WHEN E.SEX = 'M' AND STATE = 'NJ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Male_NJ',
        SUM(CASE WHEN E.SEX = 'M' AND STATE = 'CA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Male_CA',
        SUM(CASE WHEN E.SEX = 'F' AND STATE = 'NY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Female_NY',
        SUM(CASE WHEN E.SEX = 'F' AND STATE = 'NJ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Female_NJ',
        SUM(CASE WHEN E.SEX = 'F' AND STATE = 'CA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Female_CA',
        COUNT(*) AS 'Total'
    FROM #EMP E
    JOIN #JOB J ON E.JOBID = J.JOBID
    GROUP BY J.JOBNAME


    DROP TABLE #JOB;

    DROP TABLE #EMP;
```

But it's static mode if you have some other STATE and Gender you have to build this with dynamic SQL query and use EXECUTE check at this link.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Other way you can use PIVOT check at this link :

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

First, SQL queries do not support multiple levels of headers.  You can have complex header strings, but not multiple levels.

Second, you want rows with no employees.

Third, you want a total row.

So, you will need an outer join:

```
SELECT COALESCE(J.JOBNAME, 'TOTAL') as JobName,
       SUM(CASE WHEN E.SEX = 'M' AND E.STATE = 'NY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Male_NY,
       SUM(CASE WHEN E.SEX = 'M' AND E.STATE = 'NJ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Male_NJ,
       SUM(CASE WHEN E.SEX = 'M' AND E.STATE = 'CA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Male_CA,
       SUM(CASE WHEN E.SEX = 'F' AND E.STATE = 'NY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Female_NY,
       SUM(CASE WHEN E.SEX = 'F' AND E.STATE = 'NJ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Female_NJ,
       SUM(CASE WHEN E.SEX = 'F' AND E.STATE = 'CA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Female_CA
FROM JOB J LEFT JOIN
     EMP E
     ON E.JOBID = J.JOBID AND
        E.YEAR = @YEAR AND
        E.CITYID = @CITYID
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (J.JOBNAME), () );
```

If you want data for all years/cities, remove the conditions in the `ON` clause.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=98bf2f8810e7cc3b626960fadd8ec742) is a db<>fiddle.